# MySql PHP query to filter names from an exising csv

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of names in a csv string. Some of these names may exist in a table in my database. 
I need to create a query/proc. That will return a list of names that do not exist in the table.

For example if my CSV is

```
bob,frank,tod
```

and the table includes

```
bob 
frank
```

I need the query to return tod.

I'm familiar with SQL server not MySql I know how I could do this with SQL server just need some guidance to get this done with mySQL/PHP

Comment: Well, maybe you could post here a code you'd use for SQL server and we could help you to transform it under MySQL. Or you can do that using PHP (reading CSV and looping over the names) and querying the MySQL to find out the presence of each name. Anyway, you need to try something first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your CSV into a table like this:

```
SELECT 'bob' AS name
UNION
SELECT 'frank' AS name
UNION
SELECT 'tod' AS name
```

You can then use a `LEFT JOIN` to find the elements of this table that aren't in the real table:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM (
    SELECT 'bob' AS name
    UNION
    SELECT 'frank' AS name
    UNION
    SELECT 'tod' AS name
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Comment: Because that's not tedious at all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

create a temp. table in mysql and import your whole csv. 
Then query the both tables.
Something like:

```
select *
from a
where a.name not in (select b.name from b)
```

Comment: Thanks, I really hate creating temp tables. But you are correct this would work